# converting unix time matrix to real time matrix in r

Tags: r

How can I create a matrix with real time by converting an original matrix with Unix time in R?
For example,

```
User          V1                 V2
1000        1300203021       1298302123
1001        ...              ...
```

The answer  below is being completed on two values. This is very helpful. That said, for my application, I am working with a data frame that currently has 21 columns and 30000 rows, with each cell filled with unix time stamp data. How would I use your operation above & simultaneously convert each cell while preserving the **original matrix structure** (21 columns and 30000 rows)?

Answer (score 4):

Use `as.POSIXct()`:

```
R> as.POSIXct(c(1300203021, 1298302123), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
[1] "2011-03-15 15:30:21 GMT" "2011-02-21 15:28:43 GMT"
R>
```

You usually want to supply a timezone too.  The function is vectorized, so you can feed it entire columns at once.